# transfer number between users in website PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to allow users to transfer funds between accounts, but my database is not updating with the new numbers as I would like it to even though all the checks seem to be passing. Not sure if i have missed out any information that may be needed to answer the question, if i have i will update the question as soon as with the reinvent information.

Heres my code:

```
<?php
       // If our submit is set...
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Get the balance for the from user
        $fromBalance = $user->data()->money;
        // Get the balance for the to user
        $toBalance = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_POST['touser'] . "'");
        $toMoney = $toBalance->results();
        $toMoney1 = isset($toMoney['money']); 
        // Get our new amounts, but don't do anything yet!
        $newmoney1  = $toMoney1   + $_POST['amount'];
        $newmoney2  = $fromBalance - $_POST['amount'];

        // amount
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];

        // Check to make sure we have a valid amount
        if(!($_POST['amount'] || $_POST['amount'] == 0 || $_POST['amount'] == '')) {
            // Or error out!
            echo '<center>ERROR: Bad amount Specified!</center>';
        // Check to make sure we have two valid users
        } elseif($user->data()->username == $_POST['touser']) {
            // Or error out!
            echo '<center>ERROR: Cannot transfer money to yourself!</center>';
        // Check to make sure sufficient funds are available
        } elseif($newmoney2 < 0) {
            // Or error out!
            echo '<center>ERROR: Insufficient funds!</center>';
        // Check for default user selection...
        } elseif($_POST['touser'] === 'null') {
                // Or Error Out
                echo '<center>ERROR: No username selected!</center>';
        // Otherwise we are good...
        } else {
            // So we call our update functions.
            $update = DB::getInstance()->query("UPDATE users SET `money` = '" . $newmoney2 . " WHERE username = '" . $user->data()->username . "'");
            $update2 = DB::getInstance()->query("UPDATE users SET `money` = '" . $newmoney1 . " WHERE username = '" . $_POST['touser'] . "'");

            // Send a success message
            echo '<center>Transfer completed successfully, thank you!</center>';
        }
    }

    ?>
```

And the form is:

```
<form class="reg-page" role="form" action="" method="post">
<center>
Please note: Transfering funds is done at your own risk, please make sure you transfer the funds to the right person.
<br>
<br> 
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <label>Transfer $ To<span class='color-red'> *</span></label>
        <select name='touser' class='form-control margin-bottom-20'> 
        <option value="null">Select user:</option>
            <?php
                $query = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT username FROM users");
                    // Loop over all our usernames...
                    foreach($query->results() as $row) {
                        if ($row->username != $user->data()->username) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $row->username . '" >' . $row->username . '</option>';
                        }
                    }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <label>Amount $<span class='color-red'> *</span></label>
        <input type='number' step="any" name='amount' class='form-control margin-bottom-20'>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn-u" name="submit">Transfer</button>
</center>
```

Apologies if i have missed any information out that may be needed to help me. If I have i will update the question as soon as possible. 
Thank you for any help!

Comment: some basic debugging would narrow down where the error is

Comment: `$toMoney1 = isset($toMoney['money']); ` ? `isset` should return "1" for true of "0" for false? What you want with "$toMoney1" and appended to another var?

Comment: Don't really see an actual question, but here's some advice: Retrieve amount from db, change amount, set new amount = horribly bad.  Rather, update that subtracts diff from amount in one account and also update that adds diff to other account, and run it in a transaction with rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least an extra `'` in each of the `UPDATE`s. If should be `SET money="`.

Note that your implementation is subject to all sorts of concurrency and security issues. You should do `SET money = money + ?` / `SET money = money - ?` at the very least, and put at least these two in a transaction block. You should also test the result of the updates, and correctly escape everything you send to your SQL server.

Comment: Thanks, changed querys to:  $update = DB::getInstance()->query("UPDATE users SET `money` = `money` - '" . $_POST['amount'] . "' WHERE username = '" . $user->data()->username . "'"); And works great.

Answer (score 0):

- You have a rogue single `quote` in your `sql update` statements, it's not closed either.
- If you're trying to check if `$toBalance` has a result with "money" field, you're missing something.

  - My change will stop the script if it's unavailable (not set), but you can do whatever you like.
- Use `$toMoney`, not `$toMoney1` for the new balance, or you'll have some major issues.

---

You may want your code something more like...
(Code changes are surrounded by `//CHANGE START` and `//CHANGE END`)

```
<?php
       // If our submit is set...
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Get the balance for the from user
        $fromBalance = $user->data()->money;
        // Get the balance for the to user
        $toBalance = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_POST['touser'] . "'");
        $toMoney = $toBalance->results();
//CHANGE START
        if (!isset($toMoney['money']))
        {
            echo '<center>ERROR: Target account unavailable!</center>';
            exit();
        }
        // Get our new amounts, but don't do anything yet!
        $newmoney1  = $toMoney   + $_POST['amount'];
//CHANGE END
        $newmoney2  = $fromBalance - $_POST['amount'];

        // amount
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];

        // Check to make sure we have a valid amount
        if(!($_POST['amount'] || $_POST['amount'] == 0 || $_POST['amount'] == '')) {
            // Or error out!
            echo '<center>ERROR: Bad amount Specified!</center>';
        // Check to make sure we have two valid users
        } elseif($user->data()->username == $_POST['touser']) {
            // Or error out!
            echo '<center>ERROR: Cannot transfer money to yourself!</center>';
        // Check to make sure sufficient funds are available
        } elseif($newmoney2 < 0) {
            // Or error out!
            echo '<center>ERROR: Insufficient funds!</center>';
        // Check for default user selection...
        } elseif($_POST['touser'] === 'null') {
                // Or Error Out
                echo '<center>ERROR: No username selected!</center>';
        // Otherwise we are good...
        } else {
            // So we call our update functions.
//CHANGE START
            $update = DB::getInstance()->query("UPDATE users SET `money` = " . $newmoney2 . " WHERE username = '" . $user->data()->username . "'");
            $update2 = DB::getInstance()->query("UPDATE users SET `money` = " . $newmoney1 . " WHERE username = '" . $_POST['touser'] . "'");
//CHANGE END

            // Send a success message
            echo '<center>Transfer completed successfully, thank you!</center>';
        }
    }

?>
```